# AdvCheckTreeview connect to database

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I have a component from TMS named AdvCheckTreeView in which every node of a treeview has a checkbox just like CheckListBox in Additional tool palette. Now , my problem is how could I get the check state of each node and save to database.

Consider this a Checktreeview which has a treeview and checkbox:

```
PIS00
  |__PIS001
  |  |__PIS00011
  |  |__PIS00012
  |
  |__PIS002
  |  |__PIS00021
  |
```

Now, I want to get the check state of each and throw it to their respective Datafield. For Example.

```
PIS00 - Datafield/Name : DBPIS00
PIS001 - Datafield/NAme : DBPIS001
```

If I check the PIS001 then it returns a Boolean Result 'True' if not then it will become 'false' It will save the boolean result of each node or items in database wether it was checked or not.

Is that possible?

I know how to save Boolean in database if I used DBCheckbox. I just dont know on how to assign the datafield individually if its comes in treeview with checkbox since it has no datasource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this isn't a data-aware control you will have to manually iterate through and set each field accordingly depending on the node's state. Which is essentially the reverse of what you did to populate the treeview in the first place e.g.

```
var  
  I : integer;  
  lNode : TTreeNode;  
begin  
  for I := 0 to advchecktreeview1.Items.Count - 1 do  
  begin  
    lNode := AdvCheckTreeView1.Items[I];  
    MyQuery.FieldByName('RelevantField').AsBoolean := AdvCheckTreeView1.Checked[lNode];           
  end;  
end;
```

Alternatively use the relevant Node click event to set the field individually.